# PHP: Variable in array declaration

Tags: php, debugging, syntax, variable-assignment

I'm working in PHP and calling the following function from inside a `foreach{}` loop.  This function needs to accept `$subTheme` as an option parameter because the purpose is to avoid unnecessary code repetition (DRY, right?).

So, first off - here's the function:

```
/*
 * CSS needed to apply the selected styles to text elements.
 */
function this_site_text_css( $subTheme = '' ) {

    $GLOBALS['this_theme_mod']; // this is in global scope already

    $themeVarSuffix = $subTheme['var_suffix'];
    $themeClassName = $subTheme['class_name'];

    $content_bg_color  = $this_theme_mod['content_bg_color' . $themeVarSuffix ];
    $page_bg_color     = $this_theme_mod['page_bg_color' . $themeVarSuffix ];
    $primary_color     = $this_theme_mod['primary_theme_color' . $themeVarSuffix ];

    $css = 'body' . $themeClassName . '{ /* special classes */ };'

    return $css
}
```

There's more happening but it's rather tedious and just concatenates CSS as a string to return.

It's being called like this

```
$data = '';
$data .= this_site_text_css();
$subThemeArray = array(
  'theme_a' => array( 
     'var_suffix' => '_theme_a',
     'class_name' => '.theme-a',
  ),
  'theme_b' => array( 
     'var_suffix' => '_theme_b',
     'class_name' => '.theme-b',
  ),
);
foreach( $subThemeArray as $key => $theme ) {
   $data .= this_site_text_css( $theme );
}
```

I'm getting a PHP warning `Illegal string offset 'class_name'` and I'm guessing this is because PHP doesn't want me to concatenate `$themeVarSuffix` inline when declaring it at `$themeClassName`.  I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this, and I've searched all over, perhaps I haven't searched the right keywords, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Illegal string offset 'class_name'

... means that `$subTheme` is actually a `string` and not an `array`. This happens because you have a default value for it in the function declaration `$subTheme = ''` and missed to pass a value once you call it, here:

```
$data .= this_site_text_css();
```

So `$subTheme` is an empty string which has of course no index 'class_name'.

Comment: Thanks! That was it... just needed to do 
`function this_site_text_css( $subTheme = array() )`

Answer (score 1):

In `$subThemeArray` array the index `theme_class` should be called `class_name`

Comment: +1 Good catch! For others, note that the question was updated after this answer.

Comment: I appreciate the catch - but I was just writing some pseudo code so the incorrect code I posted initially is divergent from my working code and the working code was never wrong, only the pseudo code.

Comment: np, thing is that when code is posted for debugging one can never be sure what is a typo and what is a real bug in code. Anyways glad @hek2mgl got it figured out for you